# Laplace's equation with mixed boundary condition using separation of variables

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

The equation and boundary condition are defined in the picture where $T_1$, $T_2$, $T_3$, $k$ and $h$ are constant value.

[image: 1]

I am trying to use variable separation to solve the problem.
If $T(x,y)$ could be separated to $X(x)Y(y)$, then I can get the general solution of the pde:

$$X=A\cos(\lambda x)+B\sin(\lambda x)$$

$$Y=Ce^{- \lambda y}+De^{ \lambda y}$$

$$T(x,y)=(A\cos( \lambda x)+B\sin(\lambda x))(Ce^{- \lambda y}+De^{\lambda y})$$

$\lambda$ is the separation constant.

Is there anyway that I can use *Mathematica* to solve for the $A,B,C,D$ and $\lambda$?

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Implement separation of variable in _Mathematica_, or just solve the problem symbolically with _Mathematica_?

Comment: `DSolve` will use separation of variables internally for this pde. You do not have to implement it yourself.

Comment: The primary goal is to solve the pde symbolically,

Comment: A couple of points:  (1)  By redefining $T \to T - T_2$, you can make two of the BCs homogeneous.  (2)  It's not clear to me that you shouldn't also be including terms of the form $T(x,y)=(A\cos( \lambda y)+B\sin(\lambda y))(Ce^{- \lambda x}+De^{\lambda x})$ as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, I found minor issue actually after I verified with Maple. When breaking the problem into 4 problems, to make life easier for `DSolve`, the top BC, should be
`k*Derivative[0, 1][T][x, b] == h*(T[x, b] - T3)` when non homogeneous, but for the homogeneous case, it should be `k*Derivative[0, 1][T][x, b] == h*(T[x, b])` and not `k*Derivative[0, 1][T][x, b]  == 0` as I had it below. i.e. only `T3` should be set to zero.

I noticed this when I compared Maple's solution to Mathematica's and found very small difference in numerical values.

But now `DSolve` now can't solve it any more :(

So will post Maple's solution below, and post the corrected Mathematica solution, which breaks the problems into 4, but now it does not solve it.  So may be you can try `NDSolve` in Mathematica for this. May be in V 12.2 `DSolve` can do it.

### Maple solution

```
restart;
pde := diff(T(x, y),x$2)+diff(T(x,y),y$2)=0;
bc := T(0, y) = T1, T(a, y) = T2, T(x, 0) =T2, k*D[2](T)(x,b)= h*(T(x, b) - T3);
sol1:=simplify(pdsolve([pde, bc], T(x, y)) assuming a>0,b>0);
```

which gives

```
T(x,y) = (Sum(-2*(-(-T1+T2)*(-Pi*k*n+a*h)*exp(n*Pi*(2*b-y)/a)+a*((T2-T3)*(-1)^n
-T1+T3)*h*exp(n*Pi*(b-y)/a)-a*((T2-T3)*(-1)^n-T1+T3)*h*exp(n*Pi*(y+b)/a)+exp(n/
a*Pi*y)*(-T1+T2)*(Pi*k*n+a*h))*sin(n/a*Pi*x)/Pi/n/((-Pi*k*n+a*h)*exp(2*n/a*Pi*b
)-Pi*n*k-a*h),n = 1 .. infinity)*a+T1*a+x*(-T1+T2))/a
```

[image]

### Corrected Mathematica solution

```
ClearAll[T, x, y, T1, T2, T3, k, h];
pde = Laplacian[T[x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
bc = {T[0, y] == 0, T[a, y] == 0, T[x, 0] == 0, k*Derivative[0, 1][T][x, b] - h*T[x, b] == -h*T3}
sol1 = DSolve[{pde, bc}, T[x, y], {x, y}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]
```

[image]

```
bc = {T[0, y] == 0, T[a, y] == 0, T[x, 0] == T2, k*Derivative[0, 1][T][x, b] - h*T[x, b] == 0}
sol2 = DSolve[{pde, bc}, T[x, y], {x, y},   Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]
```

[image]

```
bc = {T[0, y] == 0, T[a, y] == T2, T[x, 0] == 0,   k*Derivative[0, 1][T][x, b] - h*T[x, b] == 0}
sol3 = DSolve[{pde, bc}, T[x, y], {x, y},   Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]

(* no solution *)

bc = {T[0, y] == T1, T[a, y] == 0, T[x, 0] == 0, k*Derivative[0, 1][T][x, b] - h*T[x, b] == 0}
sol4 = DSolve[{pde, bc}, T[x, y], {x, y},   Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]

(* no solution *)
```

So can't add them, since 2 solutions could not be found. need all 4.

### Original answer below (but contain error in BC)

You can solve it as follows.

`DSolve` can not handle more than one edge in Laplacian in 2D being non homogeneous at same time.

Due to linearity, the problem is broken into 4 problems, were one edge is non homogeneous at time. Then the 4 solutions are added.

So instead of doing

[image]

```
ClearAll[T, x, y, T1, T2, T3, k, h];
pde = Laplacian[T[x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
bc = {T[0, y] == T1, T[a, y] == T2, T[x, 0] == T2, k*Derivative[0, 1][T][x, b] == h*(T[x, b] - T3)}
sol1 = DSolve[{pde, bc}, T[x, y], {x, y}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]
```

Where `DSolve` does not solve it, do the following

```
bc = {T[0, y] == 0, T[a, y] == 0, T[x, 0] == 0, k*Derivative[0, 1][T][x, b] == h*(T[x, b] - T3)}
sol1 = DSolve[{pde, bc}, T[x, y], {x, y},   Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}];

bc = {T[0, y] == 0, T[a, y] == 0, T[x, 0] == T2,k*Derivative[0, 1][T][x, b]  == 0}
sol2 = DSolve[{pde, bc}, T[x, y], {x, y},   Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]

bc = {T[0, y] == 0, T[a, y] == T2, T[x, 0] == 0, k*Derivative[0, 1][T][x, b]  == 0}
sol3 = DSolve[{pde, bc}, T[x, y], {x, y},   Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]

bc = {T[0, y] == T1, T[a, y] == 0, T[x, 0] == 0, k*Derivative[0, 1][T][x, b] == 0}
sol4 = DSolve[{pde, bc}, T[x, y], {x, y},   Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]
```

And the solution is

```
sol = First[(T[x, y] /. sol1) 
     + (T[x, y] /. sol2) 
     + (T[x, y] /. sol3) 
     + (T[x, y] /. sol4)]
```

[image]

Comment: Seeing your solution here prompted me to ask a similar question I have been facing recently. I have asked it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226346/three-dimensional-laplacian-insulated-on-lateral-faces-and-convectively-exposed). Can you have a look at it. Hope referring in this way is not violating the SE code of conduct.

Comment: FYI, none of your four `NDSolve` commands (with the correct Robin BCs) return solutions in Mathematica v12.0.  I suppose that implies that Wolfram developers have been improving these algorithm recently.  Perhaps there's hope for v12.2.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert  `I suppose that implies that Wolfram developers have been improving these algorithm recently` yes, `DSolve` have been improving. some charts are here [is-mathematica-adequately-improving](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221959/is-mathematica-adequately-improving)

Answer (score 3):

> The primary goal is to solve the pde symbolically.

Then forget separation of variables, try [`finiteFourierSinTransform`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155817/1871). First interpret the PDE and corresponding b.c.s to *Mathematica* code.

```
With[{T = T[x, y]}, eq = D[T, x, x] + D[T, y, y] == 0;
  bcx = {T == T1 /. x -> 0, T == T2 /. x -> a};
  bcy = {T == T2 /. y -> 0, k D[T, y] == h (T - T3) /. y -> b}];
```

Then introduce the transform $T(x,y)=u(x,y)+\frac{T_2-T_1}{a}x+T_1$ to make the b.c.s in $x$ direction homogeneous. **This isn't actually necessary**, but will make the resulting series solution converge faster.

```
transform = T -> Function[{x, y}, u[x, y] + (T2 - T1)/a x + T1];

{neweq, newbcx, newbcy} = {eq, bcx, bcy} /. transform // Simplify
```

Eliminate derivative in $x$ direction using `finiteFourierSinTransform`:

```
tset = finiteFourierSinTransform[{neweq, newbcy}, {x, 0, a}, n] /. Rule @@@ newbcx
```

Solve the resulting ODE system:

```
tsol = u[x, y] /. 
   First@DSolve[tset /. HoldPattern@finiteFourierSinTransform[a_, __] :> a, u[x, y], y] //
   Simplify
```

Transform back:

```
sol = T[x, y] /. transform /. 
  u[x, y] -> inverseFiniteFourierSinTransform[tsol, n, {x, 0, a}]
```

[image]

Notice I've used `C` to denote $\infty$ in `sol`.

To check its validity, compare it to the numeric solution:

```
xR = 13; yR = 17;

para = {k -> 2, h -> 3, T1 -> 5, T2 -> 7, T3 -> 11, a -> xR, b -> yR};

test[x_, y_] = sol /. para /. C -> 10 // ReleaseHold;

nsol = NDSolveValue[{eq[[1]] == NeumannValue[-h/k (T[x, y] - T3), y == b], bcx, 
    bcy[[1]]} /. para, T, {x, 0, xR}, {y, 0, yR}]

Manipulate[Plot[{nsol[x, y], test[x, y]}, {x, 0, xR}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Red, Dashed}}, PlotLegends -> {"FEM", "Series(10 terms)"}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 15}], {y, 0, yR}]
```

[image]